# what is the order in which azure Startup tasks are run

Tags: azure

I have 3 startup tasks, two simple(t1, t2) and one background task(t3).
now t1, t2 must run in order, now as t3 is a background task and it uses some environment variables that are set by the task t2.

i have some doubt about how background tasks run ?
do they start with the role startup or they start running as soon as they came in the list of start up tasks.

ex. if i define the order of tasks as (t3,t1,t2) in my csdef file, does t3 will start running in background first, then t1, t2 will complete and then role start up phase will start ---> in this case i may read the environment variables before they are set

or

t3 being a background task will not start untill all the simple tasks are finished and will start with the role start up

EDIT: found that they run in order as they appear in the csdef

Now i am running into another problem 
i am setting some envrionment variables in t2 at Machine Level
and in t3 i am reading them on process level, some times t3 is able to read these variables but sometimes it reads null values

in general: are all Environment variables at machine automatically available for each process or not ?

Comment: You might try to write the current system time into a text file when each task starts (time /t >> d:\task1.txt). That might give you a hint about the task schedule.

Comment: okay i found that tasks runs in order, and doesn't matter whether its a simple, background or forground task :)
so in above case t3 will start running in background first and then t1 and t2 will run in order parallel to t3

so my order of running tasks must be t1, t2, t3

Comment: maybe you should post your findings as an answer to your own question...

Answer (score 0):

i found that tasks runs in order in which they are defined in the csdef

if u have following tasks defined in my csdef in same order

```
<Task commandLine="t1" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />
<Task commandLine="t2" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />
<Task commandLine="t3" executionContext="elevated" taskType="background"></Task>
```

so first t1 will execute, after t1 completes t2 and after t2 completes t3 will run in background and role start up phase will start in parallel

if i change the order to

```
<Task commandLine="t3" executionContext="elevated" taskType="background"></Task>
<Task commandLine="t1" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />
<Task commandLine="t2" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />
```

then t3 will run in background and t1 and t2 will run in parallel but in order